# NSURLConnection - Get HTTP status code on request failure

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

Is there any way I can get HTTP status code after NSURLConnection has failed to request? According to the documentation, I can get the HTTP status code from `-connection:didReceiveResponse:`. However, in case the request fails, only `-connection:didFailedWithError:` is called, and by far I haven't found any method to get status code inside this method.

p/s: I'm working on a VERY old, complicated project, and it's very error-prone, so I cannot use AFNetworking or NSURLSession.

Comment: Did you print out the user info of the error instance? Usually it contains the additional information.

Comment: I did try that, sadly it doesn't have the status code.

Comment: Can you add the log of the error instance, please?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the Apple docs for [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondatadelegate?language=objc) the connection:didReceiveResponse: is called only when sufficient data has been received to create the NSURLResponse object.

While the NSURLResponse object may not be available until later, it is possible for a connection to receive partial data by using the connection:didReceiveData: method.  Note that this seems to exclude the HTTP headers and only contain the "data" component of the response.  There may be a way to trigger the didReceiveResponse: early if the server knows ahead of time how much data will be transmitted although I am no familiar enough with this to confirm.

Be aware that the response data typically comes in blocks of approximately 1KiB of data each, depending on various network settings such as MTU and how often the server "flush" its output pipe.

Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure, that the status code is part of the data received by `-connctionDidReceiveData:`?

Comment: Hrm.. Seems like you are correct, only the actual "data" part is returned and the didReceiveResponse contains the actual .allHttpHeaders field.  Will require more investigation.  Thanks @AminNegm-Awad

Comment: The more I research this it seems that what you are trying to achieve would require either to create your own network stream and process the response manually, or to get access to some private methods (not recommended!!) as detailed in https://github.com/apportable/Foundation/blob/master/System/CFNetwork/private_include/CFNetwork/CFURLConnection.h

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can get the HTTP status code via the instance of `NSError` as suggested in my comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I couldn't find a way to get the http code, guess I'll have to give up on this.